# show separate bar and filename for each vim horizontal split

Tags: vim

This seems silly but I cannot find an answer. I do `vim a.txt` then `:sp b.txt` to open two `.txt` files with two panels. So the upper panel opens `b.txt` and the lower panel opens `a.txt`. See this screenshot:
[image]

When I'm working on `b.txt`, the status bar that separates these two panels is missing. This is awkward. Is there a way to config .vimrc to enable the separation bar, as well as always showing the name of each opened file?

btw, this is my ~/.vimrc file:

```
set tabstop=4
set hlsearch
syntax on
set laststatus=2
```

According to many posts, laststatus=2 should work, but not for my case. Per @romainl's request, I'm also attaching the full output of `vim --version`
[image]

Comment: See `:help 'laststatus'`.

Comment: I have append `set laststatus=2` to my ~/.vimrc. But still shown as the screenshot

Comment: That's **very** surprising. Can we see the full output of `$ vim --version`?

Comment: It is 8.2.3489.

Comment: "the full output".

Comment: I am attaching the full output as a screenshot in my question

Comment: Hmm… looking back at your first screenshot, the one-line gap between the tildes of `b.txt` and line 1 of `a.txt` suggests that the status line is actually there but made invisible by some color/highlighting issue. Could you replicate the setup of that screenshot and do `Cmd+A` to [select the whole window](https://i.imgur.com/OtHRgc9.png)? What do you get?

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure how to upload images in comment. But I tried cmd+A and got the same outcome as your screenshot.

Comment: I posted the screenshot on imgur. Anyway… it looks like a colorscheme issue or maybe one with your terminal's palette. In Vim, what is the exact output of `:verbose hi StatusLine` and `:verbose hi StatusLineNC`?

Comment: `:verbose hi StatusLine` returns `StatusLine     xxx term=bold,reverse cterm=bold,reverse gui=bold,reverse`. `:verbose hi StatusLineNC` returns `StatusLineNC   xxx term=reverse cterm=reverse gui=reverse`